# Lucene analyzer for first name

Tags: search, solr, lucene, elasticsearch

Is there a Lucene analyzer out there that tokenizes name parts with their short name equivalents (e.g. Mike and Michael, Rich and Richard, Suzie and Susan), etc?

Fuzzy match on Levenshtein distance is a solution I know, and some implementors seem to pair fuzzy match with the soundex algorithm.  Surely somebody has made a swipe at just plain listing all of these short names somewhere?

EDIT:  The toughest part of this question is where to get the synonym data from?

Comment: The US Census Bureau has some information on their website on names used in English (no guarantee that they have this, though, and it takes some googling to get at it).

Comment: This has some ideas, pretty uncommon names on it though: http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/778986.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of any specific nickname filter out there.

A [SynonymFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilter.html) would make it reasonably easy to generate though, if you had a data source for it.  This appears to be a good source of nickname data:

https://code.google.com/p/nickname-and-diminutive-names-lookup/

You would need to generate the `SynonymMap` to pass into the `SynonymFilter` ctor, which should look something like this (I think):

```
SynonymMap.Builder builder = new SynonymMap.Builder(true);
builder.add(new CharsRef("Mike"), new CharsRef("Michael"), false);
builder.add(new CharsRef("Rich"), new CharsRef("Richard"), false);
builder.add(new CharsRef("Suzie"), new CharsRef("Susan"), false);
SynonymMap map = builder.build();
```